# Getting the DownloadUrl of the Firebase storage image takes too much time

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage, firebase-app-check

I'm trying to upload an image to the Firebase storage, get the image download URL,and then save that URL into the Firestore doc. Uploading images is fast. but getting the download URL takes time (about 5 seconds). .
Also getting the following errors on the console.

> Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed.

**Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.**

I don't know whether this makes time consumption.

I can see there are already posts available related to this topic. Nothing can give a proper answer.

[image: Console Screenshot]

This is my code.

**uploading**

```
Future<String?> uploadImage(
    XFile image, String docId, context) async {
  try {
    checkConnection(context);

    Reference storageRef = bucketReference.child('$type/$docId.jpg');

    await storageRef.putFile(File(image.path));

    print('image uploaded ////////////////');

    final downloadUrl = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();

    print('got download url ////////////////');

   
    return downloadUrl;
  } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
    print(e);
    showSnackbarMessage(context, upload, 0);
    return null;
  }
}
```

**save**

```
Future<void> save(
 
  String? note,
  XFile? image,
  context,
) async {
  String? imageUrl;
  String incomeDocID = incomeCollectionRef.doc().id;

 

  try {
    if (image != null) {
      imageUrl = await uploadImage(image, incomeDocID, context);
    }
    DocumentReference incomeDocRef = incomeCollectionRef.doc(incomeDocID);

    incomeDocRef.set({
      if (note != null && note.isNotEmpty) 'Note': note,
      if (imageUrl != null) 'ImageURL': imageUrl,
 
    });

    print('saved to doc ////////////////');

    Navigator.pop(context);
  } catch (e) {
    showSnackbarMessage(context, unexpectedError, 2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try edit your uploadImage() method like this :

```
Future<String?> uploadImage(XFile image, String docId, context) async {
  try {
    checkConnection(context);

    Reference storageRef = bucketReference.child('$type/$docId.jpg');

    UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(File(image.path));
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
    String downloadUrl = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    return downloadUrl;
  } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
    print(e);
    showSnackbarMessage(context, upload, 0);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the solution. still facing the problem.